# How to insert datetime into sqlite3 database using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, datetime

I would like to insert datetime into sqlite using Python.

I tried using Python's datetime and strftime but it didn't work.

Test's time field has the type of Numeric (Datetime).

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt

rows = db.execute(
    'INSERT INTO test (time) VALUES (:time)',
    time=dt.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

RuntimeError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "'2019-05-19 17:14:25'": syntax error
[SQL: INSERT INTO test (time) VALUES ('2019-05-19 17:14:25')]

Comment: copy query and run directly in database and maybe it gives you more information about problem. Numeric may means number like timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :-

```
rows = db.execute("INSERT INTO test (time) VALUES (datetime('now'))")
```

The column type is basically irrelevant as in SQLite you can store any type of value in any type of column.

With the exception of the special **[rowid](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html)** column or an alias of the **rowid** column (if the column is defined using `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` then it is an alias of the rowid column (or with the AUTOINCREMENT keyword)). An alias of the rowid column must be an integer up to 64 bit signed.

## Working Example

```
import sqlite3
drop_sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test"
crt_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (time NUMERIC, time2 TEXT, time3 BLOB, time4 REAL, time5 INTEGER )"
db = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
rows = db.execute(drop_sql)
rows = db.execute(crt_sql)
rows = db.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES(datetime('now'),datetime('now'),datetime('now'),datetime('now'),datetime('now'))")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
for row in cursor:
    print("Time is " + row[0], "\nTime2 is " + row[1],"\nTime3 is " + row[2], "\nTime4 is " + row[3],"\nTime5 is " + row[4])
db.commit()
db.close()
```

## Result :-

> ```
> Time is 2019-07-13 08:59:28 
> Time2 is 2019-07-13 08:59:28 
> Time3 is 2019-07-13 08:59:28 
> Time4 is 2019-07-13 08:59:28 
> Time5 is 2019-07-13 08:59:28
> ```